# Variable name not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I created a program which assigns a string value to a variable.

Here is the code

```py
print("I have information for the following planets:\n");
print("   1. Venus   2. Mars    3. Jupiter");
print("   4. Saturn  5. Uranus  6. Neptune\n");
 
weight = input("Enter your weight: ");
planet = input("Enter planet number: "); 
# Write an if statement below:
if planet == 1:
  planet_name = 'Venus';
  weight = weight * 0.91;
elif planet == 2:
  planet_name = 'Mars';
  weight = weight * 0.38;
elif planet == 3:
  planet_name = 'Jupiter';
  weight = weight * 2.34;
elif planet == 4:
  planet_name = 'Saturn';
  weight = weight * 1.06;
elif planet == 5:
  planet_name = 'Uranus';
  weight = weight * 0.92;
elif planet == 6:
  planet_name = 'Neptune';
  weight = weight * 1.19;
else:
  print("Planet Not Found");
print("Your weight on " + planet_name + " is: " + weight + "kg");
```

So when I try to run the program it says `planet_name` was not found and also prints else statement

Here is the output with errors

```
I have information for the following planets:

   1. Venus   2. Mars    3. Jupiter
   4. Saturn  5. Uranus  6. Neptune

Enter your weight: 55
Enter planet number: 6
Planet Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/python/planet.py", line 28, in <module>
    print("Your weight on " + planet_name + " is: " + weight + "kg");
NameError: name 'planet_name' is not defined
```

I am unable to find what's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, since you are using python, you don't have to add `;` at the end of each statement.

Now, by default doing `input('')` returns a `string`. You have to change the type to `float` for `weight` & `int` for `planet`

```
print("I have information for the following planets:\n")
print("   1. Venus   2. Mars    3. Jupiter")
print("   4. Saturn  5. Uranus  6. Neptune\n")
 
weight = float(input("Enter your weight: "))
planet = int(input("Enter planet number: "))
# Write an if statement below:
if planet == 1:
  planet_name = 'Venus'
  weight = weight * 0.91
elif planet == 2:
  planet_name = 'Mars'
  weight = weight * 0.38
elif planet == 3:
  planet_name = 'Jupiter'
  weight = weight * 2.34
elif planet == 4:
  planet_name = 'Saturn'
  weight = weight * 1.06
elif planet == 5:
  planet_name = 'Uranus'
  weight = weight * 0.92
elif planet == 6:
  planet_name = 'Neptune'
  weight = weight * 1.19
else:
  print("Planet Not Found")
print("Your weight on " + planet_name + " is: " + str(weight) + "kg")
```

In the last `print` statement, you have to convert the type of `weight` back to `string` for printing out the statement

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `input` returns a string and `'1' != 1`.

You must either convert the string to an integer:

```
planet = int(input("Enter planet number: "))
```

or compare the value to strings:

```
if planet == '1':
    ...
```

You should also convert `weight` to a `float`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to default `planet_name` to an empty string and correctly cast `weight` and `planet`, for example:

```
print("I have information for the following planets:\n");
print("   1. Venus   2. Mars    3. Jupiter");
print("   4. Saturn  5. Uranus  6. Neptune\n");
 
weight = float(input("Enter your weight: "));
planet = int(input("Enter planet number: ")); 

# Write an if statement below:
if planet == 1:
  planet_name = 'Venus';
  weight = weight * 0.91;
elif planet == 2:
  planet_name = 'Mars';
  weight = weight * 0.38;
elif planet == 3:
  planet_name = 'Jupiter';
  weight = weight * 2.34;
elif planet == 4:
  planet_name = 'Saturn';
  weight = weight * 1.06;
elif planet == 5:
  planet_name = 'Uranus';
  weight = weight * 0.92;
elif planet == 6:
  planet_name = 'Neptune';
  weight = weight * 1.19;
else:
  planet_name = ''
  print("Planet Not Found");
print("Your weight on " + planet_name + " is: " + str(weight) + "kg");
```

->

```
I have information for the following planets:

   1. Venus   2. Mars    3. Jupiter
   4. Saturn  5. Uranus  6. Neptune

Enter your weight: 50
Enter planet number: 4
Your weight on Saturn is: 53.0kg
```

Comment: moved the default to `else`